# Проблема скачивания pdf файла через библиотеку html2pdf на ios

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Пробовал настраивать jsPDF не помогает, скачивание работает везде, кроме ios, буду благодарен за помощь

```
    const element = document.getElementById('main-****');
    const elementCopy = element.cloneNode(true);
    const elementToRemove = elementCopy.querySelector('.site-***-svg');
    if (elementToRemove) {
        elementToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(elementToRemove);
    }

    const elementToRemove1 = elementCopy.querySelector('.site-***-svg-cart');
    if (elementToRemove1) {
        elementToRemove1.parentNode.removeChild(elementToRemove1);
    }

    var opt = {
        margin: [-4.4, 2.9, 0, 0],
        filename: `ЕК{{{number}}}.pdf`,
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.5 },
        html2canvas: {
            width: 1040,
            height: 2750,
            scrollX: window.scrollX,
            scrollY: window.scrollY,
            scale: 2
        },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };

    
    html2pdf().from(elementCopy).set(opt).save();
});
```

Comment: `.save().then(() => console.log('ok')).catch(console.error)` и читайте что пишет